# IronPython + Python

Tags: python, excel

Подскажи, каким образом можно собрать библиотеку на IronPython использующую библиотеки C#, что бы после использовать ее в нативном Python?

**Практическая цель:**

Есть веб-интерфейс написанный с использованием фреймворка flask ( nginx+apache2+debian ). Хочется что бы была возможность генерировать xlsx файлы нативными библиотеками windows ( написаными на C# ).Т.к. нужна вся функциональность формата ( графики, формулы, макросы и пр ).

**Альтернативные подходы:**

Использовать библиотеки:

[Flask-Excel](http://flask-excel.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) - библиотека работает непосредственно с форматом xlsx

минусы:

1. очень скудный инструментарий
2. проблема с парсингом бинарных xls
3. нет стабильной версии у самой библиотеки и у тех от которых она наследуется

[pyloo](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyoo) - библиотека использует API libre/open office.

минусы:

1. приходится держать запущенный процесс libre/open office

PS: если есть какой-либо общий подход и для JPython/Cpython/PyPi, просьба указать и их. Так же хотелось бы знать успешные практики которые у Вас получалось применить.

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Нужно в IronPython скомпилировать скрипт в `dll` используя `clr.CompileModules`
2. Для использования полученной `dll` нужно воспользоваться модулем стандартной библиотеки python `ctypes`